# What is the mnemonic for Ctrl-Y (in normal mode)?

Tags: normal-mode, scrolling

I know "expose one more line" for Ctrl-E, but why use Ctrl-Y to expose one more line at the top?  Is there an easy mnemonic for this that I'm missing?

Comment: It goes *y'up* the file.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Bill Joy and Mark Horton wrote in [their original vi manual](http://docs.freebsd.org/44doc/usd/12.vi/paper-2.html#section10):

> If you want to see more of the file below where you are, you can hit `^E` to expose one more line at the bottom of the screen, leaving the cursor where it is. The command `^Y` (which is hopelessly non-mnemonic, but next to `^U` on the keyboard) exposes one more line at the top of the screen.

So, "next to u" was the motivation, and can serve as a mnemonic, I guess.

The Y also sort of represents an arrow pointing up (↑) if you squint a little bit (it has the head of the arrow inverted).

Comment: *if you squint a little bit* ;-)

Comment: I see control e and control y as both being "sort of to the left of the control d and control u keys they're related to".

Answer (score 22):

I like to call `<C-y>` "Yester-line"™ like "Yesterday". Explaining it along with `<C-e>` rhymes, too. "Extra-line" and "Yester-line"™.

Comment: This is brilliant and you deserve some sort of award.

Comment: Well at least he got reputation points.  I christen it "The 21 points in VI stackexchange" award

Comment: Like Vim golf, every point makes a difference.